# How come running `rails s` as daemon doesn't start Puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

When I run `rails s -e production -p 9292` (normal case), I get:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:9292
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

When I run `rails s -d -e production -p 9292` (as daemon), I get:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:9292
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

That's it. I would need to run `bundle exec puma -e production -p 9292 --pidfile tmp/pids/puma.pid -d` to get the 2nd part:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
...
```

Also where are my Puma logs? I see a blank `production.log` in my `log` folder and no other log files.

Background context: When I run `curl 0.0.0.0:9292` after running both `rails` and `puma` as daemons, I get the error `An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rails s -e production -p 9292 -d
```

Answer (score 2):

For Puma Versions Below 5, we can use `-d` option to start in background.

```
puma -e production -p 4132 -C config/puma.rb -d
```

But Puma gem does n't support `-d` option in versions above 5.

> In version 5.0 the authors of the popular Ruby web server Puma chose
> to remove the daemonization support from Puma, because the code wasn't
> wall maintained, and because other and perhaps better options exist
> (such as systemd, etc), not to mention many people have switched to
> Kubernetes and Docker, where you want to start all servers on the
> foreground

You can use this gem for starting in background.

https://github.com/kigster/puma-daemon

https://rubygems.org/gems/puma-daemon/versions/0.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Ah, seems Puma only cares about `RAILS_ENV` when used with capistrano. Can you use `RACK_ENV` or use -e instead? That should work:

```
RACK_ENV=production bundle exec puma -p 3000
```

or

```
bundle exec puma -p 3000 -e production
```

See [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/56#issuecomment-22643541)

Hope to help

Comment: Oh I don't think it was Puma that was the problem! I was using the `-e` flag anyway. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

## to kill the server

kill `cat tmp/pids/server.pid`

rails s -e production -p 9292 -d

Comment: What does `&` do?